# MySQL foreign key query returning empty

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have three tables

Let's a `demo_organization ;`

```
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| org_name           | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| org_type           | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| abn_acn_no         | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| org_url            | varchar(120) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| notes              | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| city               | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

Second one is `demo_user`

```
mysql> desc demo_user ;
+--------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type           | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | int(11)        | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_name          | varchar(100)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| first_name         | varchar(100)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| middle_name        | varchar(100)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name          | varchar(100)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| image              | varchar(10000) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| password           | varchar(80)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| role               | varchar(20)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| org_name_id        | int(11)        | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| timezone_id        | int(11)        | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
```

And third one is the `demo_meeting;`look like

```
mysql> desc demo_meeting ;
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name               | varchar(200) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| meetingID          | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| venue_id           | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| status             | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| recurring_time     | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| attendee_passwd    | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| moderator_passwd   | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date_created       | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| start_time         | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| end_time           | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| meeting_duration   | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| meeting_datetime   | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| timezone           | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| reminder           | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| duration           | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_by_id      | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
```

In third table created_by_id refers to A user of demo_user table(Foreign key)

And org_name_id(demo_user table )  refers to the demo_organization (Foreign key to demo_organization table )

**Updated**

```
mysql> desc demo_meetingroom;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| type       | varchar(200) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| expired_on | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id    | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now i am trying to get all meetings for a particular organization .

I am writing a query like

```
select meetingID ,type from demo_meeting as dm ,demo_meetingroom as dmr 
Where venue_id IS NOT NULL 
and dm.name = dmr.name 
AND created_by_id IN
  ( 
  SELECT id from demo_user WHERE org_name_id IN 
         (
         SELECT id from demo_organization where id =  
            (SELECT org_name_id from demo_user WHERE user_name = 'God') 
         )
   );
```

Unfortunately it is returning me Empty set (But there is value )

Please help me out what might i am doing wrong ?

Comment: u have described 3 tables, what about table "demo_meetingroom"

Answer (score 2):

`JOIN` the three tables instead of these `IN`'s. Something like:

```
SELECT
  dm.meetingID, 
  dm.type
FROM  demo_meeting dm
INNER JOIN demo_user         u   ON dm.created_by_id = u.id
INNER JOIN demo_organization org ON u.org_name_id = org.id
WHERE u.user_name = 'God'
 AND  dm.venue_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: @user1667633 - How it is not working? Try to use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` if you want to include unmatched rows from outer tables.

Answer (score 1):

Much better if you can use `JOIN`.

```
SELECT  a.meetingID, d.type
FROM    demo_meeting a
        LEFT JOIN demo_user b
            ON a.created_by_id = b.id
        LEFT JOIN demo_organization c
            ON b.org_name_id = c.id
        LEFT JOIN demo_meetingroom d
            ON a.name = d.name
WHERE   a.venue_id IS NOT NULL AND
        b.username = 'GOD'
```

Comment: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'a.created_by_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: yeah as you can see in the question  .Kindly check the updated question also

Comment: wierd. `a.created_by_id` is the same as `demo_meeting.created_by_id`

Comment: What about this :          $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT meetingID,type from demo_meeting dm ,demo_meetingroom dmr WHERE dm.created_by_id IN(SELECT id  from demo_user  WHERE org_name_id IN(SELECT id from demo_organization WHERE org_name IN (SELECT org_name from demo_organization WHERE id IN (SELECT org_name_id as id from demo_user WHERE user_name = '$user_name')))) AND dm.venue_id IS NOT  NULL";